# Does using a for loop to wrap async operations make those operations occur synchronously?

Tags: javascript, node.js

For example, say I want to do something with data from a bunch of urls. Let's say I put those urls in an array. Is it bad practice/wrong to do

```
for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    http.get(url[i], (response) => {
        // do something ...
    })
}
```

Basically, I want to know how this code works. Does the for loop wait for each get request to complete before incrementing i or does it do the async thing of not waiting and continuing with the program?

Thanks.

Comment: Simple answer: no

Comment: No, the loop won't wait for the functions.

Comment: @jabaa so this is perfectly okay as an async pattern? I'm very new to node and async as you might have imagined from the question.

Comment: If you push elements into an array inside the callbacks the order depends on the order the responses arrive and are completed. It's often not the order you send the requests. As long as you're aware of this this pattern is perfectly fine.

Comment: @fishgas If you *want* to do "the async thing", yes, it's perfectly ok. But waiting for all the responses is rather hard using callbacks, you'd normally use promises there.

Comment: Well, it's not an error to program this way, BUT you will find that the calling code will not know when these operations are all done, has no way of accessing all the results and error handling is typically a mess.  So, you would usually not program this way.

Comment: Asynchronous stuff in a loop is generally a lot simpler to control if you only use asynchronous operations that return promises (or pomisify them if they don't natively return promises).  Then, you can easily control whether you want to run them sequentially one after the other (using `await`inside the loop) or in parallel (with `Promise.all()` or `Promise.allSettled()`) and then it's much easier to get access to all the results and error handling is much, much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    http.get(url[i], (response) => {
        // do something ...
    })
}
```

> Basically, I want to know how this code works.

First off `http.get()` is a non-blocking, asynchronous operation.  That means that when you call it, it starts the http GET and then immediately returns and the line of code after it will execute.  Sometime LATER the http GET operation will complete, it will insert an event into the nodejs event queue and when nodejs gets back to the event queue to fetch the next event (when it finishes doing whatever it was doing), then it will call the callback associated with that event.

So, that means that your `for` loop will rip through the entire loop calling each `http.get()` which will send all the http GET requests, but it won't wait for any of the responses.

Then, sometime later, it will start calling the callbacks as each http GET finishes.

> Does the for loop wait for each get request to complete before incrementing i

No, it does not wait.  These calls are asynchronous and non-blocking so calling them just initiates the operation, immediately returns and Javascript execution continues (which in this case means the `for` loop keeps running).

> or does it do the async thing of not waiting and continuing with the program?

Yes, that's what it does (the async thing).

> so this is perfectly okay as an async pattern?

Well, it's not an error to program this way, BUT you will find that the calling code will not know when these operations are all done, has no way of accessing all the results and error handling is typically a mess. So, you would usually not program this way.

Asynchronous stuff in a loop is generally a lot simpler to control if you only use asynchronous operations that return promises (or pomisify them if they don't natively return promises). Then, you can easily control whether you want to run them sequentially one after the other (using `await` inside the loop) or in parallel (with `Promise.all()` or `Promise.allSettled()`) and then it's much easier to get access to all the results and error handling is much, much simpler.

---

Let's look at a few examples using an http library that supports promises.  In this case, I'll use the `got()` library since it's one I regularly use and it fully supports promises.  For purposes of these examples, I'll assuming we're fetching some JSON.

To run your requests in sequence,

```
const got = require('got');

async function someFunction() {
    for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {

        let result = await got(urls[i]).json();
        // do something with result
    }
}

someFunction().then(() => {
    console.log("all done");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Or, assuming `urls` is an iterable, I would more likely do this:

```
const got = require('got');

async function someFunction() {
    for (let url of urls) {
        let result = await got(url).json();
        // do something with result
    }
}

someFunction().then(() => {
    console.log("all done");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

To run your requests in parallel and collect all the results at the end:

```
const got = require('got');

async function someFunction() {
    return Promise.all(urls.map(url => {
        return got(url).json();
    }));
}

someFunction().then(() => {
    console.log("all done");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const getURL = (url) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    http.get(url, (response) => {
        
    }).then(resolve);
    // setTimeout(() => resolve(url), 1000);
  })
}

(async () => {
  for (const url of urls) {
    const contents = await getURL(url)
    console.log(contents);
  }
})()
```

Comment: This would send the request synchronously. Why would you do this? Network communication is one of the slowest operations that should be done in parallel. Nowhere in the question OP asks how to convert the async loop to a sync loop. It's just a question if the code is correct.

Comment: @jabaa his code is so incorrect, Do you know the amount of URLS in his array? no? lets say its 20,000. his code is far from correct.

Comment: Why is the code in the question incorrect? You made some assumptions that could make the code incorrect. But there are many situations where the code in the question  is completely fine. And your answer doesn't even answer the main question. It doesn't explain why you would change the code. It doesn't describe when the code could be wrong. It's just a worse version of the code in the question.